# Node micro-service continuously querying mysql db

Tags: mysql, node.js, synchronization

I am new to Node.js and I am trying to create a simple micro-service where it continuously polls records from a database, execute asynchronous jobs on those records and update the state of those records in the database once the job is done.

Basically this is my inner query and loop:

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'sitepoint'
});

con.query('SELECT * FROM records where flag = 0', (err,rows) => {
  if(err) throw err;
  rows.forEach( (row) => {
  someFunction(row, function(result,err){
     if(err) throw err;
     //Update record in db
}
});

});
```

This is a rough idea of what I'm doing, my issue is I want to do this continuously on a set interval, say every 1 minute yet I do want the interval to be calculated after processing the last row in my query. In other words I want to block until all fetched rows are processed. What are my options in node.js?

Comment: how are you planning to set an initial interval?

Comment: Don't have any plans really, open to suggestions

Comment: @TGW I want to start querying immediately and then wait for the interval but as I said its not crucial since most likely the database  will be empty at start time as it will be populated by another service.

Comment: Okay can you look at settimeout method, take a variable maybe name it time or something pass it as interval to your settimeout, once your execution is done set value of interval as whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a simple pattern used in plenty of servers, where jobs queue themselves, you get the benefit that the interval can change each time and the interval between job *completions* is fixed rather than the interval between job *starts* being fixed.

```
function getQueryInterval() {
    // Could read from a DB, Redis, etc.
    return 60000;
}

function processRow(row) {
    /* Do some good stuff with the row. */
    return Promise.resolve('OK');
}

function runQuery() {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString(), 'runQuery: Running..');

    // Return a master promise, this will only resolve when everything is complete. 
    // However as soon as an error is encountered it will reject.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let processPromises = [];
        con.query('SELECT * FROM records where flag = 0', (err,rows) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            rows.forEach( (row) => {
                someFunction(row, function(result,err) {
                    if(err) reject(err);
                    //Update record in db
                    processPromises.push(processRow(row));
                });
            });

            // Only resolve when all records are processed.
            Promise.all(processPromises).then((result) => { 
                resolve(result);
            }).catch ((err) => { 
                reject(err) 
            });
        });
    })
}

async function runQueryAndQueueNext() {

  try
  {
      await runQuery();
  }
  catch (err) {
      console.error(new Date().toISOString(), 'runQueryAndQueueNext: Error occurred: ', err);
  }

  console.log(new Date().toISOString(), 'runQueryAndQueueNext: Query complete, queuing next in ' + getQueryInterval() + ' ms');
    setTimeout(runQueryAndQueueNext, getQueryInterval())
}


runQueryAndQueueNext();
```

Comment: Sounds promising though my issue is that when I call my processing function `someFunction(row, function(result,err){
     if(err) throw err;
     //Update record in db
})` This calls a third party library that returns a callback. So my concern is that I need to wait for all callbacks to finish before returning from the `runQuery()` method

Comment: I would suggest you only resolve the Promise returned by the runQuery function once your processing function is complete.

Comment: Sorry if I sound ridiculous but as I said I am new to node.js and its asynchronous methods are driving me mad :)

Comment: They sure do! My brain has melted so many times debugging node.js code :-D

Comment: Promises are a really nice pattern in node.js, plus they are a standard way of doing things, many modules use them. It's really just a dressed up callback. But it keeps code cleaner especially when you have a bunch of functions you need to call. You can simple put the promises in an array and wait for them all to resolve using Promise.all.

Comment: I've updated the runQuery proc., it could be a little cleaner, but you get the general idea!